# Bluesnap. Build a Checkout. Expiry date select block

Tags: bluesnap

I use Build a Checkout Form https://developers.bluesnap.com/docs/build-a-form. Expiry date is input type text. Is it possible to change input to a drop-down list? If possible, how?

P.S. In the example, 1 text field. I want 2 drop-down fields, month and year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlueSnap are planning to implement drop-down select for the expiry date in their next release that is scheduled to be deployed in the end of the month.
If you wish, you can configure the checkout page with current settings and after the release you can apply the necessary adjustments.